# how to get one span tag out of multiple to to overflow its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a highlight span that I want to sit right after the **to** without messing with the width of the parent. I don't want to use absolute positioning. Is it possible to have that span be aligned with the to example and overflow the parent
Example:

```
Thank you for
your interest 
to Sign up to today's deals
```

```css
.outter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.overflowing-span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.highlight {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
 <div class="parent">
  <span>Thank you for your interest to </span>
  <span class="overflowing-span">
    <span class='highlight'>Sign up to today's deals</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no other content after the `<span>`, giving it `width: 0` could work (but this is very similar to giving it `position: absolute`):

```css
.outter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.overflowing-span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}

.highlight {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
 <div class="parent">
  <span>Thank you for your interest to </span>
  <span class="overflowing-span">
    <span class='highlight'>Sign up to today's deals</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

However, if you are okay to change your HTML a little bit, here's a *"proper"* way to do it with HTML entity `&NoBreak;`. You will also have to change the `display` of your span to `inline`:

```css
.outter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.overflowing-span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}

.highlight {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
 <div class="parent">
  <span>Thank you for your interest to</span>&NoBreak;<span class="overflowing-span">
    <span class='highlight'>Sign up to today's deals</span>
  </span>
  <span>right NOW.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hao Wu I thought that white-space: nowrap would do what &NoBreak; was doing ?

Comment: Yes, but `white-space: nowrap` can only affect within the tag, but not the content adjacent to the tag (the line break is created before the span tag).

Comment: The only thing I don't love about this approach is the &NoBreak; and having to make sure my visual studio code doesn't auto format the spans on to separate lines.

Comment: Any way to get &NoBreak; to work in jsx

Comment: Try `...</span>{'&NoBreak;'}<span>...`